# what is composer.json should be for magento 2?

Tags: magento2

From today marketplace start rejects my modules by issues in composer, it's look like:

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- The requested package sy/callback 0.1.2 exists as sy/callback[0.1.0, 0.1.1] but these are rejected by your constraint.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // stage

[Pipeline] sh

[DockerOperationsPHP71Magento22CE] Running shell script

- echo Failure

Failure

**What is need to do? anybody)**

My composer.json is:

```
{
    "name": "sy/callback",
    "description": "Extension",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0"
    ],
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Slava Yurthev",
            "email": "slavik-iii@ukr.net",
            "homepage": "https://github.com/SlavaYurthev/",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "SY\\Callback\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Magento Support Answer:

> Hi Slava,
>
> We have identified a bug within our install automated testing and
>   pushed a fix to production this morning. We are going to rerun the
>   tests today for affected extensions (I added your extension to this
>   list). You will see a separate email from us that will say either that
>   you passed or failed (for a valid reason). No action is required on
>   your part. Just be on the lookout for the email.

Answer (score 1):

When I visit your module I can't see any tags : https://github.com/SlavaYurthev/Callback-M2/tags

Have you tried actually tagging your latest commit with 0.1.2 ?

Comment: no)
but anyway error from start post is fixed, start post updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your composer json file should be like this, **EDIT**

```
{
"name": "fooman/emailattachments-m2",
"license": "OSL-3.0",
"description": "Automatically attach pdf and terms and conditions documents to outgoing sales emails.",
"type": "magento2-module",
"version": "2.1.0",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Fooman\\EmailAttachments\\": ""
    },
    "files": [
        "registration.php"
    ]
},
"require": {
    "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0",
    "magento/framework": "^100.0 | ^101.0.0",
    "magento/module-backend": "^100.0.2",
    "magento/module-sales": "^100.0.2 | ^101.0.0",
    "magento/module-checkout-agreements": "^100.0.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^6.2"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"suggest": {
    "fooman/printorderpdf-m2": "Allows attaching the order confirmation pdf to the order confirmation email",
    "fooman/pdfcustomiser-m2": "Allows to easily customise the sales pdfs while also reducing file sizes "
}
```

}

If your module is for Magento 2.2 then change PHP version to,

```
    `"php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0"`
```

This is sample JSON format which is approved by magento marketplace, You can find this extension from this [link](https://marketplace.magento.com/fooman-emailattachments-m2.html)

> Note : I am not prorating this extension, this is free extension on
>   marketplace

Comment: nope, this is not fix issue, i change version to 1.0.0 and "require" and still see these errors on technical review

Comment: also i tried copy your code and pass tech review and nothing...

Comment: Nothing means ?

Comment: i was mean - nothing changed, still see these errors

Comment: this extension Updated: 16 September, 2017, these errors start showing **from today** , 1 day ago all been fine

Comment: This extension is compatible with magento 2.2 ,

Comment: but If they have changed something then I am not sure